# Writing constraint for a tuple

Tags: c, cplex

I have defined the following tuple:

```
tuple capacity3 {
    int sup; // varies from 1 to 5
    int comp; // varies from 1 to 3
    int peri; // varies from 1 to 6
    int val3; // values corresponding to sup, comp, peri
}
{ capacity3 } aa = ...;
```

I have written my tuple as

```
aa={<1,1,1,620>,<1,1,2,610>,<1,1,3,630>,<1,1,4,620>,<1,1,5,640>,<1,1,6,630>, ...  //and so on.
```

Now I have the following constraint;

```
forall(i in I, c in C, p in P)
      sum(j in J)X[i][j][c][p]<= RHS
```

At RHS, I need to write the value defined as `val3 (620, 610 ....)` in tuple corresponding to specific `i,c and p` which are defined as `sup, comp and peri` in my tuple.

How will I write my constraint i.e. value in pace of RHS ? or I am going wrong elsewhere also?

I am new to CPLEX.

Answer (score 1):

Same question at:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/387005/writing-constraint-for-a-tuple.html

You could write:

.mod

```
tuple capacity3 { 
key int sup; // varies from 1 to 5 
key int comp; // varies from 1 to 3 
key int peri; // varies from 1 to 6 
int val3; // values corresponding to sup, comp, peri 
} 

range I=1..1;
range J=1..1;
range C=1..1;
range P=1..6;

{capacity3} aa=...;

dvar float X[I][J][C][P];

subject to
{

forall(i in I, c in C, p in P) sum(j in J)X[i][j][c][p]<= item(aa,<i,c,p>).val3;

}
```

.dat

```
aa={
<1,1,1,620>,<1,1,2,610>,
<1,1,3,630>,<1,1,4,620>,<1,1,5,640>,<1,1,6,630>
};
```